Altium Component Parameters
Is there any way to define the order of component parameters in the properties window of schematic editor?
I have found out how to define which parameters are shown initially when placing a component, using the schematic symbol editor. But I cannot figure out how to set the order...
For example, I'd like to have it list in this order:

Value
Voltage
Rating
Case/Package
MFG 1
MPN 1
...etc etc

However the default is the shenanigans shown below

Value
MFG 3
MPN 3
MPN 1
Design Item ID
Case/Package
MFG 2
MPN 2
.... etc



I'd use Cap value voltage size tolerance p/n1 p/n2 p/n3 mfg1 mfg2 mfg3

You can edit *.DbLib in a spreadsheet or SQL

Thanks D.A.S. for the reply!
Where can I find this file? We've swapped to use the Altium 365 git-based libraries ('Components' in our Workspace, NOT 'Manufacturer Part Search').
I took a look in both local project files and in the 'Explorer', but no luck...

file search //>including hidden
